# how to display data corresponding to an item selected in a spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm new to android development using eclipse and I wonder if someone could me give some tips on how to do this little apps of mine.
What I want to do is to display in text view the data or value of a selected item in the spinner. For example I have a spinner with an array of hex data 1 to F. Data F for example corresponds to an error message like " this is an error message ". When I select the data F in my spinner it will display the message "this is an error message" in the textview. I will be using several spinners and each has its own hex data and values. I wanted to be able to select from one or more spinners a hex data and display the corresponding values in text view. Below is my xml code that I started. Right now there's only 2 spinners but there will be 10 in total. Textview 1 is where I wanted the message to be diplayed.

```
<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:background="@drawable/pcb" android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView2" 
    android:text="Error message" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" 
    android:textColor="#ff000000" 
    android:textSize="15dp" 
    android:typeface="monospace" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    ></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="0" 
    android:textColor="#ff000000" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:typeface="serif" 
    android:visibility="visible" 
    android:textSize="15dp" 
    android:height="100dp" 
    android:width="200dp" 
    android:text="" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    ></TextView>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView3" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#ff000000" 
    android:textStyle="bold" android:text="mycode"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/textView4" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:textColor="#ff000000" 
    android:typeface="monospace" 
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:text="BYTE  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10"
    ></TextView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
        <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/hexicon" 
        android:entries="@array/hex" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
        ></Spinner>
        <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:background="@drawable/hexicon" 
        android:entries="@array/hex" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/spinner2" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"></Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Would greatly appreciate any ideas of how this can be done, if what I'm planning is not even possible. Sorry, I can't post an image yet.
Thanks in advance.

freeman

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `OnItemClickListener` to your Spinners and from there get the data for your TextView

On a Spinner call setOnItemClickListener() to a listener implemented by you.
In your implementation you will have a `onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` method.

Inside this you can call getItem(position) on the Adapter to get the item selected and therefore get the data from there and put it in the TextView through `setText()`

Hope it helps,
JQCorreia

Comment: Thanks JQ for your response. I'll do my homework first on how to do your suggestion. Still a bit confused on how i'm gonna get the value corresponding to the item in my spinner. My spinner only has the items 1 to F and not the actual data I want to dislplay. Where do I put the actual data?