# After item clicked in spinner, Display dialog

Tags: android

Is it possible to have a spinner that displays a dialog when a item is pressed in the list 
and is it good code and not too messy. If so could someone show me some code so i can see the make up of this done thank you

Comment: I dont get the use case, but take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/6015739/664479 and here http://stackoverflow.com/q/5689236/664479

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an item selected listener on your spinner and then while an item is selected or touched start a dialog. like this --

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Here add the Dialog you want !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you up vote me & also mark right as this the right answer please.